# Design advice: calling a method on the container object from the contained object

Tags: c++, oop, composition

I have a simple setup with

```
class Container {
    Handler h;
}
```

All the Container objects have a "warning()" method. I would like
to also have a way to output warnings from within the Handler object, but send
these warnings using the facilities of the containing object.

I do realize that holding a reference to the container in the contained object is odd (normally
the contained object should not know anything about it's container). Now, in a language
with closures I would have done it like so (imaginary syntax):

```
h.set_warning_handler { | char* message |
    this->warning(message)
}
```

but I am working in C++ and it's not a place to use Apple dialect things like blocks.
What would be the preferred way to tackle this? Or just set that reference and forget about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++11 has [closures](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

```
h.set_warning_handler([&](char const* message) { this->warning(message); });
```

`[&]` specifies to capture the context by reference (needed to capture `this`). `(…)` declares the argument list, and `{…}` the lambda’s body.

Alternatively, you *can* make the `Handler` dependent on its container. This introduces quite strong coupling so it’s better to be avoided but sometimes it makes sense (e.g. if you cannot use C++11 features yet), and the strong coupling can be weakened by using an interface (the following uses late binding; sometimes, templates might be more appropriate):

```
struct CanWarn {
    virtual void warning(char const*) const = 0;
    virtual ~CanWarn() { }
};

class Handler {
    CanWarn const* warning_dispatcher;

public:

    void set_warning_dispatcher(CanWarn const* dispatcher) {
        warning_dispatcher = dispatcher;
    }

    …
};

class Container : public CanWarn { … };
```

Comment: This would be an option but that what I am using it with only works on GCC 4.0, so that will clearly not work. Unless 4.0 somehow supported these as a draft which I doubt...